# what is ''extended runway centerline''?

Tags: aircraft-performance, performance-calculation, performance-based-navigation

When we calculate performance with fly smart，we see：‘‘Take off based on climbing on extended runway centerline‘‘.
What is the meaning of‘‘extended runway centerline‘‘？How long is Extended？

Comment: What is "fly smart"?

Answer (score 1):

The centerline of the runway is exactly what it sounds like: an imaginary *line* running right down the *center* of the runway. The extended runway centerline is what you get if you *extend* that line beyond the end of the runway. If you're on the extended centerline, and you look at the runway, you'll be looking at it directly end-on.

The extended centerline doesn't end. Since it's imaginary, it can keep going to infinity in both directions. But, it becomes less and less important to navigation as you get further from the runway (and, if you're not taking off or landing on that runway, it's not really important for anything at all).

Comment: Is the centerline itself imaginary? I thought it was painted on the runway.

Comment: @Someone Not all runways have centerline markings, especially soft-field ones. But the line itself always exists, at least as an [idealized mathematical construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry))

Comment: The extended runway centerline can be very important for ATC operations, and it is not unusual for ATC to issue instructions (to helicopters, *e.g.*) like "remain north of the Runway 16 extended centerline" or "proceed directly across the Runway 35 centerline, then continue on course."